# Why does this Java regex work inconsistently for stripping street numbers out of US street addresses?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to strip out the street number from a mailing address.

I have a regex in Java:

```
address.replace("^\\s*[0-9]+\\s+","");
```

It works on this address:

```
301 West 23rd Street
```

making it:

```
West 23rd Street
```

But when I apply it to this address, the address is unchanged:

```
70-50 69th Place
```

Instead it needs to be:

```
69th Place
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't match that string. Here is an explanation of the regular expression

```
^      Start of string. Matches successfully.
\\s*   Zero or more whitespace. Matches the empty string.
[0-9]+ One or more digits. Matches "70".
\\s+   One or more whitespace. Fails to match.
```

The character after "70" is a hyphen and a hyphen is not a whitespace character so the match fails and no replacement is made. To fix it you can put a hyphen in the character class:

```
address = address.replace("^\\s*[0-9-]+\\s+", "");
```

When the hyphen is in a character class it has a special meaning (a range of characters), except in two cases:

- when it is at the beginning or the end of the character class
- when it is escaped with a backslash (but note that two backslashes are required in a Java string literal).

Answer (score 1):

That regex will only strip out the first group of digits it encounters. It's also having trouble with the -. If you want to strip out every group of digits, including -s, do something like this:

```
address.replace("^\\s*([0-9-]+\\s+)+","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex says to find: whitespace, digits, whitespace, and then replace them with nothing.

Your "bad" string doesn't have whitespace, digits, whitespace, it has whitespace, digits, dash.

If you want to include the dash in the street number, try this: `"^\\s*[0-9-]+\\s+"`

Answer (score 0):

If I may make a suggestion... by simply using regular expressions to manipulate address data, it's like using a single jackhammer to carve Mt. Rushmore out of the mountain. It may seem to work at first, but there's still a lot of work ahead.

Have you considered addresses inputted in all forms and with the components in different orders than expected? What about street names without "th" or "st" by the number, etc etc (there are too many cases to list here).

I work for [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com), where our expertise is standardizing and validating addresses. For your task, you can hook into a CASS-Certified API of sorts to return the address, standardized and componentized (broken into pieces), so you can keep just the parts you want, *and be accurate*. I suggest you look into something like [LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/), which provides this for free. Do some research on your own, and I'll be happy to help answer other address-related questions you have.